# Zod Record with default key

Tags: typescript, zod

I am trying to create an object type like this in zod:

```json
{
    default: string,
    [string]: string,
}
```

I have tried using `z.union` to combine `z.object` and `z.record` but it does not validate as what I expected.

```js
const LocaleString = z.union([
  z
    .object({
      default: z.string(),
    })
    .required(),
  z.record(z.string()),
]);

LocaleString.safeParse({
  testing: 'abc',
}); 
/** 
* it will return `{ success: true, data: { testing: 'abc' } }`, 
* where I expect it to fail when the data is without default value
*/
```

Comment: You want an intersection, no a union.

Comment: If you look at the type `z.infer<typeof LocaleString>`, you'll see it's `{default: string} | Record<string, string>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out this and it works for my case.

```js
const LocaleString = z.object({
  default: z.string(),
}).and(z.record(z.string()));

LocaleString.safeParse({
  default: 'abc',
}); // pass

LocaleString.safeParse({
  en: 'abc',
}); // fail

LocaleString.safeParse({}); // fail

LocaleString.safeParse({
  default: 'abc',
  en: 'abc',
}); // pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply make the object not strict.

Schema:

```
z.object({
  default: z.string()
})
```

Data:

```
{
  default: 'square',
  testing: true
}
```

Result:

```
Validation Passed
```

Data:

```
{
  testing: true
}
```

Result:

```
Validation errors: 
[
  { path: "default", error: "Required" },
]
```

If you add `.strict()` to that `object()` definition, the first data will refuse to validate.

Schema:

```
z.object({
  default: z.string()
}).strict()
```

Data:

```
{
  default: 'square',
  testing: true
}
```

Result:

```
Validation errors: 
[
  { error: "Unrecognized key(s) in object: 'testing'" },
]
```